# PHP - User Profile URL From Ugly URL

Tags: php, system

Alright, I usually try to figure things out on my own, but I am stumbled. I am currently making a PHP registration/login/profile system with PHP and SQL. I am 97% finished, but I would like some help with the users' profiles.

I currently have a form where you can search for users. This is a GET form that links to "www.example.com/profiles.php?username=." I would like for it so that I can link it to something like "www.example.com/user/" or "www.example.com/profile/." I would also like the functionality of going directly to the "user/" URL.

I am sure there are rewrite rules to do this, and I have tried many. I still seem to have trouble getting it to work. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Here is my current .htaccess file (doesn't work):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)\.php$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

If this htaccess does work, what should I be linking to? Because currently, linking to the "/profile.php?username=" doesn't do anything.

Again, to clarify, I want the output from the GET form to be able to link to www.example.com/profile/USERNAME or www.example.com/user/USERNAME. I would also like for the user to access their profile by typing www.example.com/profile/USERNAME.

Comment: what does your regular expression do? did you want something like `^user/(.*)\.php$` instead?

Comment: Well I wanted the URL that was generated from the GET form which is:
    
    profile.php?username=USERNAME

To be output as something like:

    profile/USERNAME

Comment: Wait, I do not think that the problem is in the rewrite rule itself, but in my PHP script. I have my PHP script getting the username from the URL with "if (isset($_GET['username']))." How would I get the username if the username wasn't in the url with a the "profile.php?username=USERNAME?"

Comment: That’s why do you this kind of rewriting in the first place, so that your script _does_ get called as `profile.php?username=USERNAME` _internally_, and you can still access it via `$_GET['username']`.

Comment: I your RewriteRule, you are demanding that the matched URL ends with suffix `.php`. No here is the price question: Does `http://www.example.com/user/USERNAME` do that?

Comment: I understand, CBroe. I got it to work with `RewriteRule ^user/(.*) user.php?username=$1` Now when I do www.example.com/user/USERNAME it links to their profile, but no CSS. So the problem with that was that I wasn't linking to the absolute path, which caused some errors. But it all works now! Thanks for the concepts. :)